# Internals of OWIN and IIS Integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, katana

I am interested in knowing how IIS invokes the OWIN pipeline during the application lifecycle.

1. I tried to know this and found that the assembly `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` is responsible for this, but a diagram explaining this will be very helpful for myself and others that are willing to learn about OWIN.
2. With respect to OWINHost, I was able to figure out how OwinHost sets up the host and then invokes the other OMC etc.
3. Additionally, I am interested in finding out how the HttpModules that we built in can be used with OWINHost and IIS hosting.

Having filtered through the web, I stand left puzzling and quizzing about these stuff. Suitable pointers or documents will be of great help.

Links referred :

[Owin Spec](http://owin.org/spec/owin-1.0.0.html#_4._Application_Startup)
[Owin Request pipeline explanation](http://whereslou.com/2012/05/14/owin-compile-once-and-run-on-any-server)
[ASP.Net Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Here is an article that explains how OWIN middleware runs on integrated pipeline: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline

Comment: Can you let me know how the owinhttphandler is registered within the Microsoft.Owin.Host.Systemweb dll. I find that the OwinHttpModule is being registered before the application_start.

Comment: It happens in the PreApplicationStart : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I already found the OwinHttpModule Registration, I was wondering how will the OwinHttpHandler be registered in the IIS pipeline. Also, any pre-registered HttpModules in web.config is run prior to OwinMiddleware, is this the right behavior

Comment: In case if you are still looking, `OwinRoute.GetRouteData` (http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/OwinRoute.cs) uses `OwinRouteHandler` which uses `OwinHttpHandler`.  So when I think uisng routes through `RouteCollectionExtensions.MapOwinRoute` extensions will result in invoking the handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`uses the [PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to bootstrap itself. The code for it can be seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/PreApplicationStart.cs).
You can read more about the usage of the `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx).